# Photo modifies rounded rectangle to rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have the following code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SignInButtonStyle: ButtonStyle{
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color(red: 27/255, green: 57/255, blue: 255/255))
                .frame(width: 315, height: 72)
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing){
                        Image("Ellipse 4")
                        Image("Ellipse 5")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                
                    Text("Sign in")
                        .font(.custom("Manrope", size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                    Image(systemName:"arrow.forward")
                            .font(.custom("Manrope", size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            }
                    configuration.label
                }
        .frame(width: 315, height: 72)
        .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.7 : 1)
    }
}

extension ButtonStyle where Self == SignInButtonStyle{
    static var signIn: SignInButtonStyle{.init()}
}
```

The button looks like this:
[image]

The right corner is no more rounded, I am not sure how to fix this. I tried to use a mask, but not sure how to handle it properly.

This is the correct button: [image]

Comment: Did you try https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/clipshape(_:style:) ?

Comment: Since the sign-in frame is being set to a specific size, have you considered creating a single background image with that aspect ratio? That would simplify the code and clipping would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `clip` the view to shape.

```
struct SignInButtonStyle: ButtonStyle{
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        ZStack{
            Color(red: 27/255, green: 57/255, blue: 255/255) //Put color at the bottom
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
            //use this rectangle for the border/stroke
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing){
                        Image("Ellipse 4")
                        Image("Ellipse 5")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                
                    Text("Sign in")
                        .font(.custom("Manrope", size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                    Image(systemName:"arrow.forward")
                            .font(.custom("Manrope", size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            }
                    configuration.label
                }
        .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.7 : 1)
        .aspectRatio(5, contentMode: .fit)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))//Clip to shape
    }
}
```